# Append to a replaced element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can an element be replaced, and then appended to?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css"></style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){

                //Appends as desired
                $('.dont-replace')
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}));

                //Replaces but doesn't append
                $('.replace-once')
                .replaceWith($('<div/>'))
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}));

                //Replaces but doesn't append
                $('.replace-once')
                .replaceWith($('<div/>')
                    .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                    .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}))
                );

                //Replaces but doesn't append
                $('.replace-multiple').each(function() {
                    $(this).replaceWith($('<div/>'))
                    .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                    .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}));
                })

                //Replaces but doesn't append
                $('.replace-multiple').each(function() {
                    $(this).replaceWith($('<div/>')
                        .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                        .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}))
                    );
                })

                //No such thing as the replace method
                ($('<div/>'))
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'a'}))
                .append($('<p/>', {'class': 'b'}))
                .replace($('.replace-once2'));

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="dont-replace"></span>
        <span class="replace-once"></span>
        <span class="replace-multiple"></span>
        <span class="replace-multiple"></span>
        <span class="replace-once2"></span>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('elementtobereplaced').replaceWith($('<div>').append(...))`?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think that is my second attempt I showed in my original post.  No?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting you call `.append()` on the new div *first*, then pass that to `.replaceWith()`. (So closer to your fourth attempt with the non-existent `.replace()` method.)

Comment: @nnnnnn  No, I didn't try, but since did.  See original post.  That was what I was thing for my made up `replace()` method.

Comment: Guess I got to rest given your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the children to the new div element *before* you pass it to the `.replaceWith()` method:

```js
$('.replace').replaceWith(
  $('<div/>')
    .append($('<p/>', {'text': 'a', 'class': 'a'}))
    .append($('<p/>', {'text': 'b', 'class': 'b'}))
);

// Check the structure of the resulting HTML:
console.log($(".container").html());
```

```css
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <span class="replace">I will be replaced.</span>
</div>
```

(If you just chain `.append()` after `.replaceWith()` like you had tried, then you are appending to the original element that just got replaced.)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer. Here's the situation. Because you're using .replaceWith() it removes all data from the DOM and adds it again. Therefore, when you try to append to what has been replaced it doesn't work because it wants to refer to the original DOM element that is not working. You're going to have to use delegation if you want this to work using replace.

[Read the .replaceWith() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).